# Agregar contenido a un jTable a través de un jButton

Tags: java

Tengo que accionar un 'jButton2' el cual agrega información a las fila de mi 'tabVentas',tiene dos campos, "Cant" y "Descripción". Si presiono nuevamente el 'jButton2', mi campo "Cant" va ir sumando 1 mas, sin llenar otra fila (ya que es el mismo contenido).
  Si presiono otro 'jButon' se rellenara la información de la misma forma pero en la fila siguiente(con otra informacion).

```
 package elbuengusto;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */

public class NuevaVenta extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   DefaultTableModel mt4;

public NuevaVenta() {
    initComponents();

    Date fecha = new Date(); //fecha y hora actual
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //formatear la fecha en una cadena
    FechaAc.setText(sdf.format(fecha)); //setear la representacion en cadena de la fech

     //tabVentas

     String titulos4 [] = {"Cant", "Descripcion"};// creando la tabla a gusto
     String filas4 [][] = {{null, null,},
                          {null, null},
                          {null, null},
                          {null, null},
                          {null, null},
                          {null, null},
                          {null, null}};

    mt4 = new DefaultTableModel(filas4, titulos4);

    TableColumnModel colVentas = TabVentas.getColumnModel(); //para poder modificar los anchos de las columnas

    TabVentas.setModel(mt4);// para poder mostrar la tabla
    //para que te tome la modificacion del tamanio tenes que hacerlo despues de mostrar la tabla
    colVentas.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(55);
    colVentas.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);

}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    }     

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede usar [`JTable.setValueAt("testValue",1 ,1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), para cambiar los valores para esas posiciones del `JTable`, puede mirar la documentacion al final, tambien puede usar [`isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable(int,%20int)), para ver si esto es posible.

**Notas:** No recuerdo si usted tiene que actualizar, si no se le muestran los cambios trate de usar lo siguiente:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
dm.fireTableDataChanged()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html

o

```
jTable.repaint();
```

Para actualizar una celda en concreto puede usar algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
((AbstractTableModel) jTable.getModel()).fireTableCellUpdated(numero, 0);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html

Comment: Gracias angel, otra consulta, si mi tabla esta vacia,sin filas, y quiero agregar dichas filas con la informacion correspondiente, de la misma forma sin repetir informacion, como debo hacerlo? yo lo eh intentado con el metodo addRow(); pero siempre se agrega otra fila.

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez no entiendo bien su pregunta, pero igual aqui encuentra lo que buscar -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html .Pero no se si esto es a lo que se refiere; DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
     model.addRow(new Object[]{ "1", "2"});

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez he visto que usa en otro codigo suyo, de alguna manera las soluciones expuestas en esta respuesta mia, si estoy en lo cierto y esta respuesta le fue util  si no le importa acceptarla, si no es haci me gustaria que me lo comentara para barajar el suprimirla, pues tengo muchas respuestas que aun estando bien no son aceptadas por  los usuarios que las formulan, un motivo puede ser que no se vuelven a conectar a sito, y eso entre otras cosa puede hacer que no pueda volver a responder, Saludos.

Comment: Si, muchas de las respuestas que me brindaste me han sido de mucha ayuda, y creo (no me acuerdo si en todas) eh dado mi check, en este caso, realmente me eh distraído con el código y no lo eh hecho. Muchas Gracias y disculpas!

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez ningun problema y no es una obligacion, pero como te comente es porque tengo muchas como te dije, de echo nunca he pedido que se vote, solo que fueron un cumulo de circustancias por lo que te lo pregunte, para si no te fue util barajar la posibilidad de suprimir la respuesta, para no tener tantas sin valorar porque igual se podria dar el caso de no poder contestar por la baja aceptacion de las respuestas, gracias por considerarlo y espero que no te sintieras obligado a ello, nunca fue mi intencion. Saludos